# jQuery DataTable title-numeric sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jQuery DataTables plugin, and the title-numeric custom sort plugin.  The sort works ALMOST.  I have a table with the td tags containing a hidden span element like so...

```
<td><span title="5">DATA HERE</span></td>
<td><span title="4">DATA HERE</span></td>
<td><span title="2">DATA HERE</span></td>
<td><span title="17">DATA HERE</span></td>
<td><span title="10">DATA HERE</span></td>
```

Using the hidden title numeric sort on those columns, when in DESC order I get the cells with the title in the following order

```
5,4,2,17,10
```

Where I would have expected it to sort as

```
17,10,5,4,2
```

Any ideas as to what could be wrong?
Here is how I'm initializing the table...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myTable').dataTable({
          "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Filter Data" },
          "iDisplayLength": -1,
          "bJQueryUI": true,
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "aoColumns": [
               { "sType": "title-numeric" }
           ]
      });
});
```

Plugin code added before table is initialized is here:

```
    jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "title-numeric-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x = a.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
        return parseFloat( x );
    },

    "title-numeric-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "title-numeric-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's doing a string comparison. Have you tried converting a and b to integers with the `parseInt` function before comparing them?

```
 return ((parseInt(a) < parseInt(b)) ? -1 : ((parseInt(a) > parseInt(b)) ? 1 : 0));
```

etc...

Edit:

I'm not sure then :(
This exact code works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="mytable" class="display" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col1</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><span title="5">This is 5</span></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span title="4">This is 4</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span title="2">This is 2</span></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span title="17">This is 17</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span title="10">This is 10</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this as the javascript:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "title-numeric-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x = a.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
        return parseFloat( x );
    },

    "title-numeric-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "title-numeric-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );

$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#mytable').DataTable({
     "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Filter Data" },
          "iDisplayLength": -1,
          "bJQueryUI": true,
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "aoColumns": [
               { "sType": "title-numeric" }
           ]
  });
} );
```

Comment: When I try that the column won't sort at all anymore.

Comment: @Kirbos just out of curiosity, isn't that the same script that the OP gave as an (not working) example? Did you forget to include your changes?

Comment: It seems to be the same to me as well. That's why I said that I'm not really sure what the problem is, as the (seemingly) exact same code worked for me. Beats me, @mainguy. Edit: The only thing I can assume is that maybe OP didn't have the newest version of the .js or .css files, since that's really the only thing that wasn't shown in OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for my title-numeric sort extensions (I also wanted to filter out any non-numeric characters):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['title-numeric-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = a.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
    var y = b.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
    x = parseFloat(x);
    y = parseFloat(y);
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
};

$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['title-numeric-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = a.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
    var y = b.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
    x = parseFloat(x);
    y = parseFloat(y);
    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not sure what's wrong here.

I just changed your html to a second column for to see the sorting better, added `<tr>s`  and used your question code (Just removed the UI part).

```
  <tr>
    <td><span title="5">DATA HERE</span>
      </td>
      <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span title="4">DATA HERE</span>
    </td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
```

When you look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HQQXH8yO0EeRDcNf8cHS?p=preview) everything works as expected.